# При авторизации белый экран. Самописный двиг PHP 5.3

Tags: php, mysql

В логах сервера выходит такая ошибка

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'go\\DB\\Exceptions\\Query' with message 'Error SQL "INSERT INTO `effects` (`owner`,`name`,`time`,`type`,`opisan`,`from_whom`) VALUES  ("1","\xc7\xe0\xe4\xe5\xf0\xe6\xea\xe0 \xe2\xf5\xee\xe4\xe0 \xe2 \xe8\xe3\xf0\xf3",1650444146,1,"\xc4\xe5\xe9\xf1\xf2\xe2\xf3\xfe\xf9\xe5\xe5 \xf1\xee\xf1\xf2\xee\xff\xed\xe8\xe5","\xc2\xf5\xee\xe4 \xe2 \xe8\xe3\xf0\xf3") "; error="Field 'lastup' doesn't have a default value" [#1364]' in /var/www/www-root/data/www/***/enter.php:202, referer: http://***/test.php
mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:, referer: http://***/test.php
mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /var/www/www-root/data/www/***/data/DB.php(105): go\\DB\\DB->plainQuery('INSERT INTO `ef...', NULL), referer: http://***/test.php
mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /var/www/www-root/data/www/***/enter.php(202): go\\DB\\DB->query('INSERT INTO `ef...', Array), referer: http://alkior.fsouls.ru/test.php
mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 {main}, referer: http://***/test.php
mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /var/www/www-root/data/www/***/enter.php on line 202, referer: http://***.ru/test.php
```

Куда копать? Раньше все работало. Настройки сервера, PHP?

105 строка в файле DB.php

```
final public function query($pattern, $data = null, $fetch = null, $prefix = null)
{
    $query = $this->makeQuery($pattern, $data, $prefix);
    return $this->plainQuery($query, $fetch);
}
```

202 строка в enter.php

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `effects` (`owner`,`name`,`time`,`type`,`opisan`,`from_whom`) VALUES  (?,?,?i,?i,?,?) ",array($users["id"], 'Задержка входа в игру', (time()+60), 1, 'Действующее состояние', 'Вход в игру' ));
```

Comment: Текст ошибки должен приводиться ПОЛНОСТЬЮ. Если в лог попадает только часть - примите меры к получению полного текста (см. в MySQL Error Log, например). В частности - необходим код ошибки MySQL и полный фрагмент запроса из сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: Проблема с кодировкой. Похоже, БД/таблица/поле используют UTF8, а сервер шлёт не то CP1251, не то  ещё что-то. Для начала попробуйте установить кодировки крупно, выполнив в соединении предварительно SET NAMES с правильным параметром. Если не получится - копайте именно в этом направлении и используйте более частные запросы на настройку кодировки.

Comment: @Akina при чем здесь ошибка с кодировкой, когда ясно написано в конце описания - Field 'lastup' doesn't have a default value. Автор, вы не передаете ВСЕ необходимые значения для колонок, в частности, для lastup.